# how can I change the length/size ticks in a framed plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Err...Let me make clear the meaning of "the length of coordinate notation/marker".
suppose I have frame1 by

```
frame1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[12]]
```

which looks like:

[image]

I want the longer "the length of coordinate notation/marker" similar to frame2 by

```
frame2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[12], 
Epilog -> {Thick, Line[{{#, -1.1}, {#, -0.9}} & /@ Range[0, 10, 2]],
 Line[{{0 - 0.1, #}, {0.3, #}} & /@ Range[-1, 1, 0.5]]}]
```

which looks like:

[image]

as you can see frame2 is ugly due to my poor skill and the code is very...Err..
I thought something like `FrameStyle->the code must not be named` would work better,however,it turns out and `FrameStyle` only change the frame color or turn the frame to dashed or change the size of Ticks rather then Frame itself. maybe there are some secret options in `FrameStyle->you know what` I don't know?

or are there any automatic ways with similar effect without explicitly write out the `Range[-1, 1, 0.5]`s or `-1.1`s unless it's necessary,I mean, I don't want to adjust each plot one by one by hand.

all kinds of solution like frame1/.magic-replacement or powerfulfunction[frame1] or wonderfulplot[plapla...] or the methods I can't image are all welcome.

by the way,If it's possible,I hope the solution could work well more of `Names["*Plot"]`

Comment: I'm surprised that I couldn't find a dupe for this, but it seems it hasn't actually been asked before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the length of the `FrameTicks`, which is really what you want to do, is addressed in the first "FrameTicks Styling" example of the *Scope* section in the [`FrameTicks` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html).

You need to specify the actual tick values shown, like this.

```
frame2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{#, #, {0.05, 0}} & /@ Range[-2, 2, 0.5], 
     None}, {{#, #, {0.05, 0}} & /@ Range[0, 12, 2], None}}]
```

Of course, any way of getting the required specification of ticks instead of a `Range` would work just as well (e.g. `Table[{i,i,{0.05,0},{i,0,12,2}]`).

[image]

If you want minor ticks still (who does, really?), you can either construct two separate lists of ticks and `Join` them, or do something like this:

```
frame2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{#, If[Chop[Mod[2 #, 1]] == 0, Chop@#, ""], 
   {If[Chop[Mod[2 #, 1]] == 0, 0.05, 0.01], 0}} & /@ Range[-2, 2, 0.1], 
     None}, {{#, If[Chop[Mod[#, 2]] == 0, Chop@#, ""], 
   {If[Chop[Mod[2 #, 1]] == 0, 0.05, 0.01], 0}} & /@ Range[0, 12, 0.4], 
 None}}]
```

[image]

To get rid of the trailing decimal place on the x-axis, use `Floor` or `Round` instead of `Chop` for the label (second part of each sublist).

```
frame2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{#, If[Chop[Mod[2 #, 1]] == 0, Chop@#, 
         ""], {If[Chop[Mod[2 #, 1]] == 0, 0.05, 0.01], 0}} & /@ 
      Range[-2, 2, 0.1], None}, {{#, 
        If[Chop[Mod[#, 2]] == 0, Floor@#, ""], 
   {If[Chop[Mod[2 #, 1]] == 0, 0.05, 0.01], 0}} & /@ 
      Range[0, 12, 0.4], None}}]
```

Comment: But now, unfortunately, we have lost the minor tick marks. I would strongly suggest looking into alternate tick functions, such as the `CustomTicks` package, which offer the necessary flexibility.

Comment: @LLIAMnYP You can, of course, include them as well, but I chose a simple example that the OP could work with. I've added that case.